# Mounting smb with local account data

Tags: mount, login, samba

Good day!
I need to configure the smb share to be auto-mounted at boot time, and the login data for the share must be the same as when logging in. The system is in a Windows domain. I am using realmd + sssd for domain entry. Input is done with a single command

`realm join -U domain_admin domain`

Neither smb nor krb5 are used or installed on local machine. Modified the `/etc/pam.d/common-session` file to create the home directory By adding the line

`session optional pam_mkhomedir.so skel = / etc / skel / umask = 0077`

On server used FreeBSD 11.3-RELEASE-p11 (FreeNAS.amd64) and Samba 4.10.16

Users log in using credentials from AD, access rights are limited, so this option would be ideal, but I cannot find a working solution.
Tried using libpam_mount as written here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
 
<pam_mount>
 
<volume options = "uid =% (USER), gid = 100, dmask = 0700" user = "*" mountpoint = "/media/1" path = "/mnt/ServerName/Share" server = "192.168.1.2" fstype = "cifs" />
 
</pam_mount>
```

.

```
<pam_mount>
 
                <!-- debug should come before everything else,
                since this file is still processed in a single pass
                from top-to-bottom -->
 
<debug enable="0" />
 
                <!-- Volume definitions -->
 
 
                <!-- pam_mount parameters: General tunables -->
 
 
<luserconf name=".pam_mount.conf.xml" />
 
 
<!-- Note that commenting out mntoptions will give you the defaults.
     You will need to explicitly initialize it with the empty string
     to reset the defaults to nothing. -->
<mntoptions allow="nosuid,nodev,loop,encryption,fsck,nonempty,allow_root,allow_other" />
<!--
<mntoptions deny="suid,dev" />
<mntoptions allow="*" />
<mntoptions deny="*" />
-->
<mntoptions require="nosuid,nodev" />
 
<!-- requires ofl from hxtools to be present -->
<logout wait="0" hup="no" term="no" kill="no" />
 
 
                <!-- pam_mount parameters: Volume-related -->
 
<mkmountpoint enable="1" remove="true" />
 
 
</pam_mount>
```

But either I'm doing something wrong or it doesn't work.

The option of using a script would also work, but I don't know where to get the credentials and how to specify them in it.

My system: Ubuntu 20.10 (GNU / Linux 5.8.0-36-generic x86_64) with LXQt DE ver 0.15.0
p.s. sorry for possible errors and inaccuracies, I'm new to Linux and use google translate.

Comment: Sounds like you are using Samba, shares and sssd. If this is the case, are you are aware that you can no longer use sssd with Samba ?

Comment: Good day!
Could you please elaborate on why I can't use sssd with Samba?
I also did not understand how this relates to my question, because I did not intend to use sssd for automounting.

Comment: You gave very little info about what you were mounting, but there was a possibility you were using sssd with Samba. The problem with Samba and sssd goes back to when Samba 4.8.0 was released, before this release, the 'smbd' daemon (the fileserver daemon) could talk directly to AD, after the release, it had to go via winbind. Unfortunately, sssd uses its own version of the winbind libs, so winbind and sssd are incompatible. You can either use sssd for authentication or Samba, you can no longer use both together.

Comment: Sorry, I really gave little information. I am using realmd + sssd for domain entry. Input is done with a single command `realm join -U domain_admin domain`  on local machine. Modified the /etc/pam.d/common-session file to create the home directory By adding the line `session optional pam_mkhomedir.so skel = / etc / skel / umask = 0077 `
On server used FreeBSD 11.3-RELEASE-p11 (FreeNAS.amd64) and Samba 4.10.16

Comment: @RowlandPenny  If I understood you correctly, then I will not be able to access smb share via sssd.
So I need to use Kerberos + Samba + Winbind to join the computer to the domain and access the smb share via winbind, right?

Comment: If you are using Samba >= 4,8.0, then you cannot use sssd. It isn't supported by anyone, not even red-hat. If you require Shares in a domain, then you must use the smbd & winbind binaries, kerberos is optional but highly recommended.